# API Rest - Many to One

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Estoy intentando crear una relacion one to many , mi problema es que cuándo hago una petición con la entidad que tiene el ManyToOne esta no devuelve nada se limita a darme un error de `Expected ':' instead of 'a'`.

Las entidades son las siguientes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teams", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class Team implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    //Otras propiedades...

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
}
```

Y por parte del `@OneToMany` es la siguiente :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //Otras propiedades...

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="country")
    private List<Team> teams;
}
```

El repositorio:

```
@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team, Long> {

}
```

Y el controlador:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
public Team getPersona(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return teamRepository.findOne(genericMethods.toLong(id));
}
```

Pues bien cuándo quiero obtener el país del equipo me da el error que he comentado antes, ¿alguien sabe porqué?

Había pensado en poner la propiedad `@JsonIgnore` en la entidad `Team` al ManyToOne y añadir un atributo haciendo que sea One To One.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "book_detail_id")
private Country countryReturn;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el stacktrace? ¿Dónde te da ese error? ¿Es un error de compilación o de ejecución?

Comment: El error llega al momento de realizar la petición , el problema está en que no se si tengo mal montado la relación.

Comment: Puede que el error se deba a una recursión infinita. Revisa lo que indica la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37848789/5587982) en la que ocurre un caso similar al tuyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltó especificar el join column en tu propiedad manyToOne:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "book_detail_id")
private Country countryReturn;
```